# scale object with smooth animation with css

Tags: css

I saw some site in which Once you scale the browser, or more the object. The object usually move with smooth animation.
Example, If you add margin of any element `50px`, rather to suddenly apply `50px`, its animate the object. ( Although its fast, but there is animation. )

Even I tried to find those example/site, but its out of my head now.

I am going to build simple Angular Project but like to embed that `css` library for smooth animation of object in my project.

if you point of some `css` library.

Comment: You need to use _CSS transitions_ to animate the CSS changes.  Google: `css transitions`

Answer (score -1):

You can find a nice selection of CSS transitions at https://easings.net/en, then you have to add your transition to the element you want to animate smoothly, setting the CSS attribute you want to apply easing on, the time of the transition and the type of transition.

Example:

```
transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.445, 0.05, 0.55, 0.95);
```

This, as you can see in the following fiddle, will apply transition easing on all CSS attributes of the selected object (that can be transitioned), and it will last 0.6 seconds.